Translation of characters
Good Morning , could anyone translate this for me please, inlaid on a bronze vase which may be from the Song Dynasty
Thankyou
Philip

(R)師善堂, (L)永保用.

Thanks very much for your help

Thanks very much for your help –
Pip Schofield
